# specified cast from a materialized 'System.String' type to the 'CityType' type is not valid. - enum support in entity framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a class:

```
class CityDetails
{
   Id int,
   //other attributes
   CityType Type;
}
```

I am using EF. I am trying to get data from a view and populate it in a list of `CityType`. `CityType` class has a property by name `"Type"` of type `CityType` enum. The view in sql server has a column by same name "Type" and it has values which correspond to the enum element names. The following code is giving me error:

```
List<CityDetails> l = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<CityDetails>(VIEW_QUERY).ToList();
```

**Error:**

The specified cast from a materialized 'System.String' type to the 'Domain.Models.Views.CityType' type is not valid.

Enum support has been available since EF 5.0. I am using EF 6 Alpha 2.

Comment: You say "enum element names", which makes me suspect that you store the string representations of the enum, not the int values (which you should do).

Comment: The column is varchar.

Comment: Doesn't EF support conversion of varchar to enum values ?

Comment: In Entity Framework, an enumeration can have the following underlying types: `Byte, Int16,  Int32,  Int64`, or `SByte`

Comment: @Blam I just copied from this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh859576.aspx